# File.ReadAllText() results in error - Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#

I have eventually found the issue with my code.

My code breaks at the following point  String vehicle = **File.ReadAllText(result);** error message - **Illegal characters in path.**

Not sure how to fix this any help much appreciated, full code below;

```
  //Get Response
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            //Here you got the JSON as string:
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            **String vehicle = File.ReadAllText(result);**

            // Write the text to a new file named "Response.json".
            var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Respone.json");
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is clear - you have illegal characters in the path of the filename.  Your comment in the code indicates you're getting a JSON string, so you'll probably want to **parse** the JSON to get the filepath.

Comment: and what is the final value of `fileName`? is it what you expect?

Comment: Can you post what `result`'s value is after the `streamReader.ReadToEnd();` call?

Answer (score 0):

That's cause `File.ReadAllText()` excepts the file path you want to read and not the file content which you are getting from `streamReader.ReadToEnd()`

Your code line below looks redundant to me since `var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();` anyways going to get you the content.

```
 String vehicle = File.ReadAllText(result);
```

Comment: The diagnosis is most likely correct, but the `var result` is a JSON string (according to the OP's comment in the code), so they'll most likely need to parse the JSON first to get the filepath value.

Comment: @Tim, may be but can't infer it from the said comment *//Here you got the JSON as string*. He is getting the content from a webrequest ... how can you say that return is a file path?

Comment: Not to nitpick (just trying to make a good answer better and more useful).  Even if they're reading a *.json file, I'd expect the result to still be a string of JSON, which in that case would still need to be parsed.  If OP can post the contents of `result` we'll be able to better help him.

Comment: @Tim, am not saying you are not correct but just saying that not completely agree since that's not clear from post. But either way, Yes the JSON string needs to be deserialized

Comment: I removed String vehicle = File.ReadAllText(result); now receiving a new error Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Respone.json' is denied. How do you save the data to a Json file on web app?

Comment: @Tom, error is pretty clear and it says you/your program don't have access to `'c:\windows\system32` folder

Comment: @Tom you should not use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` from a IIS app, you should instead be using `Server.MapPath(@"\Respone.json")` or similar.